# MySQL Query to get count of unique values?

Tags: mysql, database

Hits Table:

```
hid | lid | IP
1   | 1   | 123.123.123.123
2   | 1   | 123.123.123.123
3   | 2   | 123.123.123.123
4   | 2   | 123.123.123.123
5   | 2   | 123.123.123.124
6   | 2   | 123.123.123.124
7   | 3   | 123.123.123.124
8   | 3   | 123.123.123.124
9   | 3   | 123.123.123.124
```

As you can see, there following are the unique hits for the various lid:

```
lid 1: 1 unique hit
lid 2: 2 unique hits
lid 3: 1 unique hit
```

So basically, I need a query that will return the following:

```
lid | uhits |
1   | 1     |
2   | 2     |
3   | 1     |
```

Anybody know how to get that?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
Select lid, count(distinct IP) as uhits
from hits
group by lid
```

Comment: I've reformatted your code by indenting each line with 4 spaces. See the formatting help to the right of the edit-screen (and +1 for correct answer)

Comment: +1 for a good answer (and you beat me to it, too). Forgive my edit, but I took the liberty of removing an extra (unbalanced) close parenthesis.

Answer (score 7):

Until you start getting into really complicated queries, SQL is made so it reads quite like a natural sentence. So first, if you can describe exactly what you want out of your query, you've already half written the SQL.

In this case, you can describe your problem like:

> Get `lid` and the aggregate count of unique `IP` from my table for each `lid`.

The only thing that remains is to translate this, using SQL keywords. The important ones here being:

- *get* -> `SELECT`
- *count* -> `COUNT`
- *unique* -> `DISTINCT`
- *aggregate..for each <field>* -> `SELECT <aggregate function>..GROUP BY <field>`

So, your sentence above starts to look like:

> `SELECT` `lid` and the aggregate `COUNT` of `DISTINCT` `IP` `FROM` my table `GROUP BY` `lid`.

Removing unnecessary words, and cleaning it up to use SQL syntax leaves the final query:

```
SELECT hits.lid, COUNT(DISTINCT hits.IP) AS uhits
FROM hits
GROUP BY hits.lid
```

Comment: +1: For first to submit an answer with correct formatting and without any errors.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT lid, COUNT(DISTINCT IP)  
FROM hits  
GROUP BY lid
```

Answer (score -2):

You need use group by:

```
SELECT lid, count(*)
    FROM Table
    GROUP BY lid
```

Comment: Actually, group by makes them distinct.