# Django ORM most occuring value

Tags: django, data-annotations, django-orm

I have a model where basically i am Tracking users' activities. I want to know what is the page the user have accessed `MOST.`

### Here are my modals.

```
class Visitor(models.Model):
    session_key = models.CharField(max_length=40, primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='visit_history', null=True, editable=False)
    ....

class Pageview(models.Model):
    visitor = models.ForeignKey(Visitor, related_name='pageviews')
    url = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    method = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
    view_time = models.DateTimeField()
```

Here is my query.

```
 Pageview.objects.values('visitor__user__first_name', 'visitor__user__last_name', 'visitor__user').annotate(url_count=Count('url')).annotate(url_count_unique=Count('url', distinct=True))
```

Here i am getting users number of urls visited, and number of unique urls visited. 
Here i also want to know which is the url user have visited the most?

### EDIT

Translation of my query.

```
Goto PageViews and count the occurring of unique URLS.(how many times a url have occurred.) and give me the one that have most visited count against each user.
```

I hope the question is clear, if not let me know.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832305/mysql-query-to-get-count-of-unique-values) is a SQL statement which does what you want. and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7255076/group-by-and-distinct-values-in-group) is a annotation-based way which may be of some use.

Comment: This didnt help me out, I have these values, these counts (total count, and unique count). Now i want to know what is the url that have most entries in the db against some sessionID

Comment: Check my EDIT for more info.

Comment: do you mean something like: "for each user, give me its most visited link and count"?

Comment: Thats exactly what i am looking for each user i need Total urls visited, and a Most visit url of that user.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO you're better off with a [many-to-many](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships) relationship. You would have something like:

```
class VisitedURLs(models.Model):
    page = models.ForeignKey(Visitor, ....)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, ....)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

and the original models become something like:

```
class Visitor(models.Model):
    members = models.ManyToManyField(PageView, through='VisitedURLs')

class PageView(models.Model):
    url = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    method = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
```

In this case, you can use the count/distinct on the `visitedURLs` model and when you get an object of that type you'll have a FK to a Visitor object (which would give you the user...) and a FK to the URL.

Another way is to explicitly count each unique visitor/url combination and store it somewhere. Depending on usage (e.g. if you want to compute/display this often) you may be better off with the dedicated storage.

Comment: In this case i must have the URL + METHODS in the pre-filled in the `PageView` Models?

Comment: Yes imo, because you can have many users accessing the same page with the same method. This is just normalising the db a bit. You'd have to see if the sample above fits your purpose or you need to tweak it. IMO (again) any extra info you may need can placed either in the `Visitor` or `PageView`.

Comment: Thanks, i will definitely give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that i have come up with.

```
Pageview.objects.filter(visitor__user_id=user['visitor__user_id']).values(
                'url').annotate(page_count=Count('id')).order_by('-page_count')
 if max_visited_node:
                user['max_visited_node'] = max_visited_node[0]
```

by this way i can get the count of the all the pages the user have visited. then i order them by that count and then i get the top first element which contains the `URL` and `page_count`.

This is what i was looking for. the suggestion of `Laur lvan` is worth  considerable.